# Entity Framework Query Nested Query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am new to the entity framework and am trying to convert the following query into the correct function calls.

```
Select Distinct a.nodeId FROM 
    (SELECT *
    FROM reportContents
    Where fitId = '29' and reportId = 
       (select max(reportId) 
       from reportContents
       where fitId = '29')
     ) a Where (a.nodeId IS NOT NULL)
```

I know this query does what i want, however i'm not sure how to translate that into the entitiy framework!

Here was my attempt.

```
var prevSelectedNodes = db.reportContents.Where(
f => f.fitId == id).Select(
f => f.nodeId).Distinct().ToList();
```

I need to somehow put a .Select() in the where call.  However that kind of thing dosen't seem possible

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is reportId unique (pk)?

Comment: Looks like Ksven has already answered, but my advice if your new to EF is try not to think of it as querying a bunch of tables. EF is composed of objects, not relational tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can't make two LINQ nested lambda expression. You can do it with two requests :

```
var maxReportId = db.reportContents.Where(r => r.fitId = "29").Max(r => r.RepordId);
var result = db.reportContents.Where(r => r.fitId == "29" && r.reportId == maxReportId && r.nodeId != null).Select(a => a.nodeId).Distinct().ToList() ;
```

Comment: If you add the first linq statement into the second statement, I would expect it to generate a single SQL statement.

Comment: As written is should do it in one statement. If the first line was terminated with a .ToList() it would force it to be executed separately. Basically it gathers up the work until something actually needs the results.