# It is possible to query my case with single query using EF? (where condition for entity and another one for nested entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities nested to each other, they have one-to-many relation themselves.

For me it requires two queries that to get the enabled modules (Module.IsEnabled == 1) and their ModuleScreen property populated by the also enabled (ModuleScreen.IsEnabled == 1) ModuleScreen objects.

Is there a way to query this by one query?

I already met [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513724/entity-framework-query-nested-query) question where the problem is the same and the accepted answer shows that it requires two queries.

```cs
public class Module
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int IsEnabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<ModuleScreen> ModuleScreen
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

public class ModuleScreen
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int IsEnabled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Module Module
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that projecting what you need onto an anonymous type:

```
var query=context.Modules
                 .Where(m=>m.IsEnabled == 1)
                 .Select(m=> new {  ModuleId= m.Id, 
                                    ModuleScreen=m.ModuleScreen.Where(m=>m.IsEnabled == 1)
                                 }
                        );
```

In case you don't want to work with an anonymous type, you can also create another class to save the info you want to project:

```
public class ModuleDTO
{
   public int Id{get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<ModuleScreen> ModuleScreens{get; set;}
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
var query=context.Modules
                 .Where(m=>m.IsEnabled == 1)
                 .Select(m=> new ModuleDTO{ Id= m.Id, 
                                            ModuleScreens=m.ModuleScreen.Where(m=>m.IsEnabled == 1)
                                          }
                        );
```

[DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is nothing more than a container class that exposes properties to save the info you want to project. DTOs help to further decouple presentation from the service layer and the domain model.